# output operation is not performed over a file with full buffering

Tags: lua, buffering

This fragment does not write to file a stream of 90 characters after the buffer is full

"full" means that an output operation is executed when the buffer is full, or when we explicitly flush the file. By writing out:write(string.rep("A",90)) and opening the file with notepad I can see the text.

This fragment does not write to the file

```
out = io.open("E:\\file","w")
out:setvbuf("full",90)
out:write(string.rep("A",89))
out:write("A")
```

On the other hand this fragment does write to the file

```
out = io.open("E:\\file","w")
out:setvbuf("full",90)
out:write(string.rep("A",90))
```

This might seem a simple question, but what actually surprises me is that rather that writing the text to the file, the first fragment does not write anything due to such a trivial change. Why does this happen? By the way, I am using Lua 5.3.4.

Comment: Not surprisingly, the same thing happens in C.